# CSS Treeview (nested lists), display as table

Tags: html, css, treeview, multiple-columns

I would like to get a table like display for a HTML structure with nested lists + dl/dt/dd list as cells for a given row.

So far, here is what I could do : 
[image: current result]

With the code :

```
<ul class="treeview">
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>item1</dt>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <ul>
      <li class="last">
        <dl>
          <dt>subitem</dt>
          <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </dd>
          <dd>
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt>item2</dt>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
      <dd>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS :

```
ul.treeview li dl dt,
ul.treeview li dl dd {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.treeview li dl dt {
  width: 200px;
}

ul.treeview li dl dd {
  width: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wt6gd2f2/

The issue is with the nested list, for which the checkboxes are not aligned with sub-level list. Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly because of default paddings and margins, so you'll have to reset those first.

nested li (a new default padding, you can set this to whatever):

```
li ul { padding-left:25px; }
```

dd:

```
ul.treeview li dl dd { margin:0; }
```

.. now you can add a negative margin (to the first!) dd to bring it the left:

```
ul.treeview li ul dl dd:first-of-type { margin-left:-25px; }
```

You **could** just skip to the last line, but since each browser has their own default margins/paddings, it might be better to set the indent yourself.

New CSS:

```
ul.treeview li dl dt,
ul.treeview li dl dd {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.treeview li dl dt {
  width: 200px;
}

ul.treeview li dl dd {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.treeview li ul {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

ul.treeview li ul dl dd:first-of-type {
  margin-left:-25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some solution where the negative margin value for dd was not hardcoded, but indeed if we hardcode the positive margin value for nested list as well, then is works like a charm!